# Multiple Promises in Ember won't resolve in the template

Tags: ember.js, promise, ember-data

I'm stuck trying to return the value of a bunch of promises.

To explain the situation: there are 4 models - the **student**s in a **group** have a **score** for each **objective**.

So I've made a component into which I pass an **objective** and the **group**. The component then handles the requests to the store to look up each student's **score** for that **objective**, and return the average.

The code seems to work, the console.logs give me exactly what I want, right up to the end, but the promises won't resolve into the template - I get the { object Object }, which I believe is the unresolved promise.

Something I'm missing here? Is there an extra step needed when waiting for multiple promises to resolve?

I appreciate this is a little specific, when I understand the answer I'll try and rephrase the question.

Component Code:

```
    averageScore: Ember.computed(function(){
    var students = this.get('group.students');
    var objective = this.get('objective');
    var store = this.get('store');
    var _this = this;

    // Create an array of promises of each student's scores
    var promises = [];
    students.forEach((student) => {
        var studentId = student.get('id');
        var objectiveId = objective.get('id');
        var newPromise = store.queryRecord('snapscore', { 'student' : studentId, 'objective': objectiveId });
        promises.pushObject(newPromise);
    });
    // When promises resolve, find and return the average
    return Ember.RSVP.allSettled(promises).then(function(scores){
        let scoreTotal = 0;
        let scoreCount = scores.length;
        console.log("Score count is " + scoreCount);
        scores.forEach((score)=>{
            console.log("Student's score is " + score.value.get('score'));
            scoreTotal = scoreTotal + score.value.get('score');
        });
        console.log("ScoreTotal is " + scoreTotal);
        var average = scoreTotal/scoreCount;
        console.log(average);
        console.log(typeof(average));
        return average;
    });
}),
```

The component's template then simply returns **averageScore**.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed property is not promise aware. So don't return the Promise inside computed property and generally don't do any set inside computed property.

In your case, you can have property named `averageScore` and do write your code in any of the component life cycle hook methods.(may be `init` or `didReceiveAttrs` hook). You can set the result to `averageScore` property `this.set('averageScore',result)`.

If you still want to make computed property to promise aware then follow this [ember igniter link](https://emberigniter.com/guide-promises-computed-properties/)

Comment: Could have sworn I'd done it before... guess not! Perfect answer, thanks for your time. Used didReceiveAttrs to set the property.